# JQuery function for fixed navbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Since bootstrap fixed navbar doesn't work for me for some reason, I decided to find a JQuery solution for this. I want the menu bar to be fixed once it's been reached by scrolling down (not by default). I tried different classes and id's in the selector, but it wouldn't work. I have the ready handler and JQuery is imported in the head.

HTML:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
         <div id="logo" data-lead-id="logo-id">
                <a id="logo-link" class="leadstyle-image-link" style="max-width: 232px; max-height: 232px;"><img src="./bootstrap-remake_files/Ztm0behQInDnkGpy_6VQNCZ-C8TObFubrNfYi14TuSEPNKrV3G0_GvdxRowtf1U2n9aAuCxw25g3Ih9vXX5Y=s0" alt="Logo" style="max-width: 232px; max-height: 232px;"></a>
           </div>
             <div class="navigation-navbar">
               <ul class="navigation-bar navigation-bar-left" data-lead-id="tabs-nav-id">
               </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>
```

JS:

```
var position = $("nav").offset().top;

$(document).ready(function() {
function stickyHeader() {
  if (position < $(document).scrollTop()) {
    $("nav").addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
  }
 }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  stickyHeader();
});
```

CSS:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: why is $(document).ready not wrapping all the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when

```
$(document).ready
```

wraps the whole code

Also, you had a couple of extra closing tags

Finally, if you want make it fixed after some scrolling mrather than as soon as the scrolling starts, then you just have to add a number to the conditional

```
if (position < $(document).scrollTop() - 500)
```

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/y0u3gL9k/

Comment: It won't fix at all. First suggestion didn't do the job.

Comment: It turns out it worked, just didn't have a high z-index.